# Fix position for a time-series of graphs

Tags: graphviz

I have I have a (time-)series of directed cyclic graphs. Every time step has only a few modification over the past one. Is there a way to fix (maybe not completely) the position of the notes, so that the changes become more evident.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same necessity to fix a part of nodes (the graph was bilobed). I needed to fix the nodes from one lobe. I tried to use graphviz but then realised that it didn't have such an option. That's why I wrote my own code on Matlab for bilobed graphs. Probably you'll have to cope with the same.